# Одновременные правки вопросов

Tags: обсуждение

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/464679/revisions

Я так понимаю, я и, и @Vlad from Moscow сделали одинаковую правку примерно одновременно. При этом в третьей ревизии указано число добавленных символов, но нет никаких изменений.

Собственно вопрос: видит ли пользователь, делающий правку, что сообщение уже было изменено? И что произошло бы, если бы правки были разными? Первая была бы отменена, а вторая сделана на основе предыдущей ревизии?

Answer (score 5):

Одна из правок была бы отклонена, но автор правки узнает об этом только если будет просматривать свою активность.

> Дух сообщества♦ проверил данный объект 16 сен в 11:20: Отклонить
>   Правка конфликтует с последующей правкой.

[Пример такой правки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29458)

Comment: Эм.. А это точно хорошая идея, так поступать с правками?

Answer (score 1):

[В дополнение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1713/6), если кто-то внес правку до того, как вы отправили вашу, вам должна быть показана специальная всплывающая подсказка в верхней части страницы, которая говорит о том, что кто-то другой обновил сообщение во время вашей правки.